# .htaccess remove part of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

I´m not feeling good asking this question (there are already a lot of good answers + tuts here). But after hours of trial I need help.

THE PROBLEM:

Due to an CMS Migration URLs have changed a bit. Old URLs are safed in a Database. Before I change ever link in Mysql I thought it would be much faster to do an .htaccess rewrite of those links. What I want is:

change

```
index.php/aktuelles?id=369:netzwerk-forst-und-holz-unterfranken-startet-ab-12-2012-&catid=1:news
```

to

```
index.php/369:netzwerk-forst-und-holz-unterfranken-startet-ab-12-2012-&catid=1:news
```

means simple cut the

```
aktuelles?id=
```

of the URL. Here my trials:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^aktuelles\?id\=$ $1 [R=301]
#RewriteRule (.*)/index.php/aktuelles?id=(.*) $1/$2 [R=301]
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

kind regards,

tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. This should cut out the `aktuelles?id=` from the provided URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^]+]+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(aktuelles)$ $1/%1? [L, R=301]
```

It's untested - please tell me if this worked for you.

Comment: hi nlsbshtr, thanks a lot for your help. something is goning on but not exactly what i want. without your rewrite I got an 404. with your rewrite a get a page but not the wanted? the url still looks the same. seems that it rewrites, but i cant´t see to what? any clue?

Comment: hey, no prob. unfortunately  I cannot post the real url. thinking for a way to setup a demo.